# Get hidden content from Website using PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, phantomjs

I am trying to scrape all the content of a specific page of TripAdvisor. Using the code bellow I am getting all the .html code with all the content to scrape. What I would like to do with PhantomJS is manipulate the page to select 3 things before downloading all the html:

- Select sorting by 'Date'
- Select 'Any' language
- Expand all the 'More' button for all the reviews to display them all.

I attached a screenshot to make it more clear.

http://www.tripadvisor.com/Restaurant_Review-g187234-d2631590-Reviews-Le_Bedouin_Chez_Michel-Nice_French_Riviera_Cote_d_Azur_Provence.html#REVIEWS

```
// scrape_techstars.js
var webPage = require('webpage');
var page = webPage.create();

var fs = require('fs');
var path = 'reviews.html'

page.open('http://www.tripadvisor.com/Restaurant_Review-g187234-d2631590-Reviews-Le_Bedouin_Chez_Michel-Nice_French_Riviera_Cote_d_Azur_Provence.html#REVIEWS', function (status) {
  var content = page.content;
  fs.write(path,content,'w')
  phantom.exit();
});
```

Can anyone with experience with this JS library tell me how to execute these actions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to add an onLoadFinished function. If it were me I would inject jquery and use that to interact with the dom.

```
page.onLoadFinished = function() {
  page.includeJs('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js', function() {
    page.evaluate(function() {
      // do dom stuff here
    });
  });
};
```